# How to send invoice with pay now link automatically in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmailer

I want to send the invoice with checkout link automatically via email when customer order product in woocommerce ( Although manually email can be sent )

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [override](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) the default Email Invoice template or create a custom email template and add the payment link using [get_checkout_payment_url()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/#section-5).